# ng-click in angular directive - pass function from root scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Fixed the issue, here is the final fiddle that shows it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/tfLeexdc/

I have a directive:

```
var StepFormDirective = function ($timeout, $sce, dataFactory, $rootScope) {
    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            context: "=",
            title: "="

        },
        template: '<h3>{{title}}</h3><form id="actionForm" class="step-form"></form><button ng-click="alert()" type="button">Save</button>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the `alert()` do something from the controller?

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/tfLeexdc/

Comment: You don't have a controller in this directive.  Where is your controller? Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: Also - a Fiddle goes a *long* way towards helping us solve an issue like this for you.

Comment: I have a method in the controller, `$scope.saveActionForm = function(){ ...}` and I want to be able to pass that function into the directive scope and call it.

Comment: @cale_b - see my edit for the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular can be twitchy, so I've built a whole new fiddle to demonstrate all of the "glue-up" pieces you need to make this work.

First, you weren't passing the properties through to the directive, so I've made that adjustment:

```
// You have to pass the function in as an attribute
<hello-directive list="osList" func="myFunc()"></hello-directive>
```

Second, you were using `onclick` instead of `ng-click` in your template, which was part of the problem, so I made that switch:

```
// You need to use "ng-click" instead of "onclick"
template: '<h3>{{list}}</h3><button ng-click="func()" type="button">Button</button>',
```

And lastly, you need to bind the function in the scope of the directive, and then call it by the bound name:

```
scope: {
  list: "=",
  // Bind the function as a function to the attribute from the directive
  func: "&"
},
```

[Here's a Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/34ag4xxp/1/)

All of this glued up together looks like this:

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <hello-directive list="osList" func="myFunc()"></hello-directive>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Angular Directive';
  $scope.osList = "Original value";
  $scope.stuffFromController = {};
  $scope.myFunc  = function(){ alert("Function in controller");};
};

var HelloDirective = function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      list: "=",
      func: "&"
    }, // use a new isolated scope
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: false,
    template: '<h3>{{list}}</h3><button ng-click="func()" type="button">Button</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      }
  };
};

myApp.directive("helloDirective", HelloDirective);
```

Comment: Odd, I had almost exactly the same thing but bound the click method to `elem` in the link function and examined the target to see if it was the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to execute a function defined somewhere else, make sure you pass it in by the `scope` directive attribute.

Here you can do:

```
scope: {
  context: '=', 
  title: '=',
  alert='&' // '&' is for functions
}
```

In the place where you using the directive, you'll pass the "expression" of the function (meaning not just the function, but the actual invocation of the function you want to happen when the click occurs.

```
<step-form-directive alert="alert()" title=".." context=".."></step-form-directive>
```